# Underline all initials after a tab

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

In my Indesign Style (CS6 on Windows 7) I want to apply the style `underline` to all initials that come after a tab.

```
NASCAR    National Association for Stock Car Racing
```

So the initials all get underlined in the expansion to indicate the letters for the acronym.  I am making a list of acronyms, so I want to grep this.

Here is what I have:

```
(?:(?<=\t))(\<.)*
(?<=\t)(\<.)
```

These will only underline the first letter after the tab.

So I thought of just underlining capital letters in the expansion, because in acronyms it's not always just the first letters of words:

```
(?<=\t)((?i)[A-Z])
```

But that does the same thing.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution 1

You can achieve this with 2 Grep styles (in the right order).

First catch all uppercase characters and apply underline character style to this first query:

```
\u+
```

Then catch all characters before tab and apply a new character style set with no underlining:

```
.+(?=\t)
```

[image: grep1]

## Solution 2

For an 'all-in-one' solution, try this:

```
\u(?!.*\t)
```

Which basically would translate as *Catch all uppercase characters except those followed by the pattern 'Any character (zero or more times) followed by a tab'*

[image: grep2]

Comment: Solution 2—very creative!

Comment: Solution 2!  This is absolutely perfect. I don't even have to manually underline anything of the characters.  I had actually derived the idea already of using capitals to cause the underlines, but I couldn't figure out how to get them on all the ones after the tab and got pretty close with this:  `(\u+(?=\l))`.  But yours is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

It’s all depends of your actual text...
If you just have a bunch of lines with Acronymes you can use this simple one.

```
\u(?=\l+)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  However, this also underlines letters in the acronym itself - nothing before the tab should get underlined.

Comment: How do use this without affecting what comes before the tab?